# make matrix from 1d array

Tags: python

I have an array  `[(0, None),(0, 1000),(0, 3000)]` and need to make 30x3 matrix from it, so that it will look that:

```
 [(0, None),(0, 1000),(0, 3000)],
 [(0, None),(0, 1000),(0, 3000)],
 [(0, None),(0, 1000),(0, 3000)],
 [(0, None),(0, 1000),(0, 3000)],
 [(0, None),(0, 1000),(0, 3000)],
```

...

I try to append

```
for i in range(29):
   bnds=bnds.append(bnds)
```

But it doesn't work.

Please suggest how this can be resolved

Comment: What are the dtypes involved? Can you show initialization code for the first array so we can reproduce your example?

Comment: You show lists of tuples, not numpy arrays

Comment: What's the significance of the `None`?  That isn't an integer,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do just:

```
your_list = [your_list] * 30
```

Comment: Thanks, but, in this case I will have 1-d array, but I need 3d

Comment: @YelizavetaChachura You don't even have an array/matrix. So of course you'll never get an array/matrix out of the operation without any type conversions. You really should take a look at the python and numpy documentations on what lists and arrays are.

Comment: @YelizavetaChachura if you build a numpy array out of that you will see it is 3d

Answer (score 0):

To get a 3d numpy array you can do this:

```
yourlist=[]
for i in range(30):
    yourlist.append([(0, None),(0, 1000),(0, 3000)])
yourarray=np.asarray(yourlist)
```

This is based on your comments, as your question is asking for a 2d matrix.